# Fill input according selected checkboxes (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some checkboxes in my web page:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="alphabet" name="alphabet" value="A"> A <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="alphabet"name="alphabet" value="B"> B <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="alphabet"name="alphabet" value="C"> C <br />

<br />

<input type="text" id="selected" />
```

Is there any way to fill a input camp "toggling" these checkboxes?

The final result maybe something like:

```
A, B, C...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code by listening to `change` event and then setting the value.

```js
(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').change((e) => {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
      var curVal = $('#selected').val();
      if (curVal) {
        $('#selected').val(curVal + ', ' + e.currentTarget.value);
      } else {

        $('#selected').val(e.currentTarget.value);
      }
    } else {
      var curVal = $('#selected').val().split(',');
      var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== e.currentTarget.value)
      $('#selected').val(filteredVal.join(','));
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="alphabet" name="alphabet" value="A"> A <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="alphabet" name="alphabet" value="B"> B <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="alphabet" name="alphabet" value="C"> C <br />

<br />

<input type="text" id="selected" />
```

Comment: It works flawlessly on Stack debug mode... But on my VS debugging, not. I think that's why my HTML check input returns an attribute like: checked="checked"

Comment: @HudsonMedeiros if it works here, it should ideally work in yours as well. Can you check for any typo or errors, please? It would be great if you can share a fiddle of what exactly you are trying to achieve.